# Collection not updating on form submission

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a complex model that looks like this:

```
public class ModelOne()
{
    //other stuff
    public ModelTwo modelTwo {get;set;}
}

public class ModelTwo()
{
    //other stuff
    public List<ModelThree> modelThrees {get;set;}
}

public class ModelThree()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
}
```

And a main view

```
@model ModelOne

@using (Html.BeginForm("blah", "blah", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "blah" }))
{ 

    //other form fields

    <div id="partial">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("partialView", ModelOne.modelTwo.modelThrees);
    </div>

     <input id="submitForm" type="submit" value="Submit" />    

}
```

And a partial view for ModelThree

```
@model IList<ModelThree>

<table>
    //header
    @{for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
            <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m[i].Type)
                    .Filter("contains")
                    .Placeholder("Select type...")
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
                    .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                        new SelectListItem() {
                            Text = "Some type", Value = "SomeType"
                        },
                        new SelectListItem() {
                            Text = "Other type", Value = "OtherType"
                        }
                    })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 250px;" })
                )
            </td>
        </tr>
    }}
</table>
```

Everything with the exception of the `ModelThree` collection submits on the form submission.

`ModelThree` binds initially as it should, if I add objects to my list in the constructor they render as expected but are never updated when I submit the form. Whether I add items (I excluded the add logic from this example) or update existing ones via the generated dropdown lists.

What do I need to do to have this submit correctly? The generated HTML looks normal with indexing, as I understand it should figure out how to bind it from there.

Note: I have also tried generic dropdownlist instead of kendo combo list, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
<div id="partial">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("partialView");
</div>
```

...

```
@model ModelOne

<table>
    //header
    @foreach (var model3 in Model.modelTwo.modelThrees)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => model3.Id)
            <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => model3.Type)
                    .Filter("contains")
                    .Placeholder("Select type...")
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
                    .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                        new SelectListItem() {
                            Text = "Some type", Value = "SomeType"
                        },
                        new SelectListItem() {
                            Text = "Other type", Value = "OtherType"
                        }
                    })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 250px;" })
                )
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This sounds to me like a model binding issue. Since you are passing in a second argument to your `RenderPartial`, all of your parent model context is being lost, and the helpers are not rendering the correct name attributes on your input elements.

Comment: That did it, thank you! FYI The for loop was still required though to allow for unique names.